# Is it possible to Override Variables in Java?

Tags: java, variables, inheritance

I want to have Classes extending a Superclass where only the Variables differ, the Methods stay the same. This is for an example of a Decorator Pattern. The Superclass implements an Interface, which forces the Methods to be overridden, but the Methods require variables that should be changed. The Code is the Following:

```
interface wearable{
    int getItemColdResistance();
    String getItemName();
}

abstract class BaseWearable implements wearable{
    boolean addsColdResistance = true; //This is just because I need an Example of a Base-Decorator
}

class Underwear extends BaseWearable{
    String name = "Underwear";
    int itemColdResistance = 1;

    @Override
    public String getItemName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemColdResistance() {
        return itemColdResistance;
    }
}

class Shirt extends BaseWearable{
    String name = "Shirt";
    int itemColdResistance = 2;

    @Override
    public String getItemName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemColdResistance() {
        return itemColdResistance;
    }
}
```

So the Variables name and itemCodeResistance differ and *must* be defined in each Subclass, but the Methods stay exactly the same. How can I write general Methods in the Superclass and change the Variables needed in those Methods in the Subclasses? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want something like that:

```
interface Wearable{
    int getItemColdResistance();
    String getItemName();
}

abstract class BaseWearable implements Wearable{
    boolean addsColdResistance = true; //This is just because I need an Example of a Base-Decorator
    private String name;
    private int itemColdResistance;
    BaseWearable(String name, int itemColdResistance) {
        this.name=name;
        this.itemColdResistance = itemColdResistance;
    }
    @Override
    public String getItemName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemColdResistance() {
        return itemColdResistance;
    }

}

class Underwear extends BaseWearable{
    Underwear() {
       super("Underwear",1);
    }
}

class Shirt extends BaseWearable{
    Shirt() {
        super("Underwear",2);
     }

}
```

BTW: The interface name should start with uppercase character

Comment: I think this is what gets the closest as to what I'm looking for, I think I just had a wrong imagination of what's possible within Java. Thank you very much for your answer, it's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible.

But it is not at all clear why you need different variables and don't just set the variables to different values.

Comment: I wanted a way to make it compulsory to change the variables, so I thought having abstract variables would solve that problem - like having to define them every Subclass. Without them, the compiler is totally okay with the Subclasses not changing the variables at all and returning values such as "undefined" and 0, which would lead to confusing Erroneous Code down the line - especially when stuff gets more complex.

Comment: That's what constructors are for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way.

Neither should there be. The variables are not part of the visible interface. (Or rather: Should never be.)